# Angular multiple params with the same name

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

URL have multiple params with the same name:

```
?myarray=value1&myarray=value2
```

How can I retrieve this URL using `$state.href`

What should I pass as params?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Because in API that I use `$state.href` generate URL and I want it to generate URL in this format

Comment: This is a valid question.  Some APIs require multiple queryparams with the same name.  Yes, it's silly, but if you need to make calls to Solr, for example, you'll be grateful for the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, that you are "lucky guy" because that feature is just part of the recent release of the `UI-Router`. Check it here:

### [API Reference $stateProvider](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

#### Firstly example:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home?myarray',
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'myView.html',
        controller: 'MyController',
      }
    },
    params: {
      myarray: { array: true, },
    },
  }
```

#### Doc extracts

The `$stateProvider.state(name, stateConfig)` takes object **`stateConfig`**, which has a property:

> **`params`** (optional)   object
>
> A map which optionally configures parameters declared in the url, or defines additional non-url parameters. For each parameter being configured, add a configuration object keyed to the name of the parameter.
>
> Each parameter configuration object may contain the following properties:
>
> - value
> - array
> - squash

And this is definition for setting array:

> **array** - `{boolean=}`: *(default: false)* If true, the param value will be treated as an array of values. If you specified a Type, the value will be treated as an array of the specified Type. Note: query parameter values default to a special "auto" mode.
>
> For query parameters in "auto" mode, if multiple values for a single parameter are present in the URL (e.g.: **`/foo?bar=1&bar=2&bar=3`**) then the values are mapped to an array (e.g.: { **`foo: [ '1', '2', '3' ]`** }). However, if only one value is present (e.g.: **`/foo?bar=1`**) then the value is treated as single value (e.g.: **`{ foo: '1' }`**).

```
params: {
    param1: { array: true }
}
```